# Toggle button not working properly in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building my first Vue app. I have some experience with React, and I'm trying to make a simple movies list in Vue.

There are two bugs in my app - both related to the button toggling:

1. OnClick I want to change hideImg, and display the other image. I can only toggle it once. It refuses to return back to neutral state.
2. OnClick I want to toggle show the video. It works properly - opens a video on button click, and then if I click another button it closes the old video and shows new one. But once I open all 4 videos, I cannot show or close any more videos.

It seems like I can only toggle each element ONCE.

Am I missing something?

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(name, index) in movies" :key="index" class="movieContainer">
    <div class="center">
      {{ name.name }} {{ name.duration }}
      <button
        @click="name.hideImg = !name.hideImg && toggle(name.id)"
        class="watchBtn"
      >
        <p v-if="name.hideImg">►</p>
        <p v-else>▼</p>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div v-show="name.id == open">
      <video controls="controls" autoplay name="media">
        <source
          :src="require(`@/assets/movie${index + 1}.mp4`)"
          alt="video"
          type="video/mp4"
          width="500px"
        />
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  methods: {
    toggle(id) {
      this.open = this.open === id ? null : id;
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      movies: [
        {
          name: "Pokemon",
          duration: "1hr 12min",
          hideImg: true,
          open: null,
          id: 1,
        },
        {
          name: "Digimon",
          duration: "2hr 37min",
          hideImg: true,
          open: null,
          id: 2,
        },
        {
          name: "Transformers",
          duration: "1hr 51min",
          hideImg: true,
          open: null,
          id: 3,
        },
        {
          name: "Kiepscy",
          duration: "1hr 51min",
          hideImg: true,
          open: null,
          id: 4,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin: 60px auto 0;
}
.watchBtn {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.watchBtn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 191, 107);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.movieContainer {
  margin: 5px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
.movieContainer video {
  width: 500px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple quick things that may help. Your `toggle()` could be cleaned up a bit. You can do both of those actions in the `toggle()` method.

And you're accessing the video incorrectly. `this.open` is looking for a data property named `open` at the top level of your `data()`, and it's not finding it. So you need to drill down into `movies` to get the right property.

Also, your indices for the movies start at 1, but the loop is starting at 0, so things are off by 1.

I put together a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-whm7lc?file=src/App.vue) so you can see what I'm talking about.

Here's the code for posterity:

```js
<template>
  <div v-for="(movie, index) in movies" :key="index" class="movieContainer">
    <div class="center">
      {{ movie.name }}
      <button
        @click="toggle(movie.id)"
        class="watchBtn"
      >
        <p v-if="movie.hideImg">►</p>
        <p v-else>▼</p>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div v-show="movie.open">
      <!-- <video controls="controls" autoplay name="media">
        <source
          :src="require(`@/assets/movie${index + 1}.mp4`)"
          alt="video"
          type="video/mp4"
          width="500px"
        />
      </video> -->
      <h2>It's Working!</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  methods: {
    toggle(id) {
      this.movies[id - 1].hideImg = !this.movies[id - 1].hideImg
      this.movies[id - 1].open = !this.movies[id - 1].open
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      movies: [
        {
          name: "Pokemon",
          duration: "1hr 12min",
          hideImg: true,
          open: false,
          id: 1,
        },
        {
          name: "Digimon",
          duration: "2hr 37min",
          hideImg: true,
          open: false,
          id: 2,
        },
        {
          name: "Transformers",
          duration: "1hr 51min",
          hideImg: true,
          open: false,
          id: 3,
        },
        {
          name: "Kiepscy",
          duration: "1hr 51min",
          hideImg: true,
          open: false,
          id: 4,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin: 60px auto 0;
}
.watchBtn {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.watchBtn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 191, 107);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.movieContainer {
  margin: 5px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
.movieContainer video {
  width: 500px;
}
</style>
```

I commented out the video for testing because I don't have it locally. But I think with this the toggle buttons work as expected.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! I see what I did wrong - I secretly suspected that something with movies was missing, but after hours of trial and error I was exhausted. Once again - thanks a lot! Also you helped me learn how to use console.log - which will be super useful for testing purposes.